# is there any way to call a function(in another python file) and get the same return in Django view

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get a return from a function that is in similarity.py (function name returnTablewithURL) to Views.py. When I print the variable df in similarity.py it gives the output in dataframe. Like this:

```
    Similarity (%)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_f...        0.876818
https://knowyourphrase.com/the-quick-brown-fox            2.371295
```

I want to get the same output for fileupload function in views.py. So I tried to call the function from views (meaning from fileupload function) but it shows something in numbers. Output( with the help of print statement to check if it is same):

```
<function returnTableWithURL at 0x000001D3631311F0>
```

I have tried some other methods but in vain. It would be really helpful if i could use some suggestion and help

**Views.py:**

```
def fileupload(request):
    # Handel file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Process for handeling the file snd store it on mongodb
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            #Contain process for extracting data in a file and storing them in DB as textfield
            newdoc.fileData = request.FILES['docfile'].read()
            newdoc.username = request.user            
            newdoc.save()
            # Redirect to the document list after post
            result(newdoc.fileData)

            # Here i am trying to get the result from 
            # returnTableWithURL function. This function is in 
            # another python

            dframe = returnTableWithURL
            print(dframe)
            return render(request, 'report.html',{'df': 
            dframe})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() #A empty, unbound form
            
    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.filter(username=request.user)

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request,
        'home.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

Here is the function and python file. function takes an parameter.

**Similarity.py**

```
def returnTableWithURL(dictionary):

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Similarity (%)':dictionary})
    
    print(df)
    return df
```

Here is the HTML page where I want to show the dataframe

**report.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plagirism Report</title>
</head>
<body>

    

    {{ df }}

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are printing the df in function, but in your html you are calling a dataframe and expecting a table to show up. that's how it won't work. you will have to create table structure and push data into that.

Comment: is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Yes you can make a dict out of df and write loop in your jinja html to get the values and print them in page.

Comment: Yes you can make a dict out of df and write loop in your jinja html to get the values and print them in page.

Comment: another thing df in html is not same as df in function.... df in HTML is a context

Comment: you might want to add few lines of your df that you want to print in your html along with your html. that would be something specific that you might want to do here.

Comment: can I call a function in context? sorry for asking so many questions I am new to Django .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so i failed to do it in normal process like by calling the df variable but I succeded it using json. I followed this solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rendering-data-frame-to-html-template-in-table-view-using-django-framework/

I hope it helps other